# Why does my instance not get "popped" when I use the list.pop() method to cut the last item on the list?

Tags: debugging, pygame

It's a pygame question, and the list basically holds the positions that the user has been in. However instead of being a snake of length "x", it just goes on and on from wherever the user starts.

Find the code posted below, I think the issue is primarily with where the pop is placed, but I can't be sure. If you think so, just CTRL + F "pop"

```
import pygame    
running = 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

UP = (0,-1)
DOWN = (0,1)
LEFT = (-1,0)
RIGHT = (1,0)
#Creating a worm
class WormFromTheFuture:
    def __init__(self,initial_x,initial_y,wormlength):
        self.x = initial_x
        self.y = initial_y
        self.length = wormlength
        self.body = []
        self.dirx = 1
        self.diry = 1
    def worm_assignment (self, arbtry):
        self.dirx, self.diry = arbtry
    def worm_moves (self):
        self.x += self.dirx
        self.y += self.diry
    def worm_draw (self, surface):
        self.body.insert(0, (self.x,self.y))
        if len(self.body) > self.length: 
            self.body.pop()
        for x,y in self.body: 
            surface.set_at((x,y), (255,255,255))

wormy = WormFromTheFuture (320,240,10)
while running:
    wormy.worm_draw(screen)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = 0
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: wormy.worm_assignment (UP)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: wormy.worm_assignment(DOWN)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: wormy.worm_assignment(RIGHT)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: wormy.worm_assignment (LEFT)  
    wormy.worm_moves()

    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear the screen with black using a function like:

```
def clear(self, screen):
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

And just call that before any other drawing occurs:

```
wormy.clear(screen)
wormy.worm_draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be forgetting to undraw the part of the worm that's being popped.

Comment: Thank you, how do you suggest I undraw the popped part of the worm?

Comment: You could redraw whatever was there originally.